# how to convert MB to BYTE using bash / awk

Tags: linux, bash, awk, size, numeric-data

we need to calculate BYTE value from MB values

example

```
10  --> 10485760 
100 --> 104857600
```

Comment: These days, MB rather refers to _megabyte_ (1,000,000 bytes), while MiB refers to _mebibyte_ (2^20, 1,048,576 bytes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply by 1024 twice (or by 1048576 once).

---

In `bash` (or any `sh`-shell):  `$(( 10 * 1024*1024 ))`

With a variable:

```
s=10
m=$(( s * 1024*1024 ))
```

To get the specific output that you show:

```
for s in 10 100; do
    printf '%-3d --> %d\n' "$s" "$(( s * 1024*1024 ))"
done
```

---

In `awk`: `10 * 1024*1024`

Reading megabytes from standard input (single column input) and printing the corresponding number of bytes:

```
{ print $1 * 1024*1024 }
```

To get the specific output that you show:

```
printf '10\n100\n' | awk '{ printf("%-3d --> %d\n", $1, $1 * 1024*1024) }'
```

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, with `numfmt` from GNU coreutils:

```
printf '10\n100\n' | numfmt --from-unit=Mi
10485760
104857600
```

Answer (score -4):

echo "10|100|1000" | awk -F"|" '{ 
gsub("10","10  --> 10485760"); 
gsub("100","100 --> 104857600");
gsub("1000","1000 --> 1048576000");
print }'

Comment: why are you doing arithmetic with string substitutions?